# Sharepoint Calculated Column - LEFT()

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to find the substring of the start time (I just want the date) field using a calculated column in SharePoint 2010 on a date/time field.

I am using the =LEFT() command (please see attached images)

As you can see the formula validates but doesn't show the correct output

Please note I am restricted to out of the box SharePoint only, SharePoint designer has been disabled and this being a Calendar List, infopath is out of the question.

[image: List View]

[image: Calculated Column]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEFT function is doing a substring on SharePoint's internal representation of the date, which is a number.

To get just the date, you can simply have your fomula as: =[Start Time] and set the Date and Time Format to Date Only.

Comment: Thanks, there was me trying to overcomplicate it! Simple and effective, thanks!